# C++ member function templates takes member function pointer as the template argument

Tags: c++

I have a class with some very similar member functions `f_a`, `f_b` and `f_c`.

```
class A {
public:
    double f_a() {return 1.0;}
    double f_b() {return 2.0;}
    double f_c() {return 3.0;}

    template <double (A::*any_f)()>
    double my_f() {
        return any_f()
    }
}
```

So my question if it's possible to use the class this way without making these member functions static.

```
int main() {
    A a;
    a.my_f<&A::f_a>();
    a.my_f<&A::f_b>();
    a.my_f<&A::f_c>();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you read about functors?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, but I dont want to overload() operator in my class since it's a class with some other methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
class A {
public:
    double f_a() {return 1.0;}
    double f_b() {return 2.0;}
    double f_c() {return 3.0;}

    template <double (A::*any_f)()>
    double my_f() {
        return (this->*any_f)();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.my_f<&A::f_a>();
    a.my_f<&A::f_b>();
    a.my_f<&A::f_c>();
}
```